# Rails: Two tables has_many a single table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

What's a better way to achieve this?

```
class Opf < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :budget_items, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'budget_id'
end

class Voucher < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :budget_items, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'budget_id'
end

class BudgetItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :opf
    belongs_to :voucher
end
```

Opf and Voucher could has_many BudgetItem:

```
Opf.budget_items.build
Voucher.budget_items.build
```

The problem I get with this setup is they share the same foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such cases you should consider [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). They are easy to establish and maintain.